# Why do you have to use keyword "this" instead of class name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

this is code from a react.js tutorial and the "this" keyword represents the App class. So my question is why can I not just write the class name instead?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person';

class App extends Component {

state = {
 persons: [
  { name: 'Max', age: 28 },
  { name: 'Manu', age: 29 },
  { name: 'Stephanie', age: 26 }
 ]
}

render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Hi, I'm a React App</h1>
    <p>This is reallyyyyyyyy working!</p>
    <button> switch name</button>
    <Person name={App.state.persons[0].name} age={this.state.persons[0].age} />
    <Person name={this.state.persons[1].name} age={this.state.persons[1].age}>My Hobbies: Racing</Person>
    <Person name={this.state.persons[2].name} age={this.state.persons[2].age} />
  </div>
 );
// return React.createElement('div', {className: 'App'}, 
React.createElement('h1', null, 'Hi, I\'m a React App!!!'));
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: You state "the `this`" keyword represents the App class". The answer to your question is right there in that misconception. The `this` keyword does **not** represent the App class. As clearly explained in tens of thousands of tutorials and blog posts and answers right here on SO, it represents the **current instance of the App class**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because in JavaScript, when you specify a class name (in particular, inside a class), you get a reference to the class, not to the current class instance. The instance properties and methods are not available through its class. Meanwhile `this` represents the current instance.

```
class App {
    test() {
        console.log(App); // "class App ..."
        console.log(this); // "[object Object]"
        console.log(App.foo()); // "1"
        console.log(this.foo()); // "2"
        console.log(this.constructor.foo()); // "1"; this.constructor is a reference to the current object class
    }

    static foo() {
        return 1;
    }

    foo() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "when you specify a class name inside a class", but this should just be "when you specify a class name". It makes no difference whether you specify it inside or outside. For completeness, you probably should explicitly state the exception of `static` methods, especially since one is shown in the example. For clarity, you probably should say "**instance** properties and method".

Comment: @torazaburo I wrote "inside a class" intentionally to highlight this difference of JavaScript from other languages where class name is used instead of `this`.

Comment: In what language(s) is a class name used instead of `this`? Just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Because

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class. It can
>   be used to access members from within constructors, instance methods,
>   and instance accessors.

This rule is followed by any Object Oriented programming language. However, If you force your class to take instance with its name then it has to be static (Not the class itself but properties and methods).

For your purpose we can create `App` class as module

```
class App {
  hello() { return 'Hello World'; }
}

export let AppInstance = new App ();
```

**Usage**

```
import { AppInstance } from './App';
AppInstance.hello();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot parse the English "If you force your class to be take instance with its name", or "create a common". Perhaps you could rewrite those parts..